# Copy binary file from other system with builtin shell commands only

Tags: bash, unix, shell, remote-access, disaster-recovery

I accidentally  just have removed critical shared library and no one dynamically linked executable can't be run now. For example, even `/bin/ls` shows `error while loading shared libraries: libunwind.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I even can't copy removed file back because ssh stops working (`scp` is unable to initiate new connection).  And I can't remove the disk from the computer and write right file back: it's embedded device and there is no removable disk.

Only I have -- is still existing shell session, which I shouldn't close under anycircumstances: because I will be unable to open new session.

How can I transfer binary file (shared library) from other system via only builtin shell commands (like echo, printf, read, etc...) ?

Comment: PS: there is no statically linked shell like sash, no busybox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the built in /dev/tcp TCP bus in Bash:

http://fibrevillage.com/scripting/603-dev-tcp-examples-and-trouble-shooting

You should be able to formulate a HTTP request using that, so that you can pull the file in via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If /dev/tcp isn't available alternative solution can be used, as described below.

On target machine give following command:

```
(while read -s l; do echo "$l"; done) > temp.txt
```

Then on PC perform following actions:

1. install `x11-utils` (need `xwininfo`) and `xdotool`;
2. determine window id of the console, in which ssh session live: use `xwininfo` for it;
3. give following command to transfer data:

```
od -An -v -tx1 file.bin | (while read l; do xdotool type --delay 0 --window 0xa0000d "$(echo -e \"$l\r\")"; sleep 0.02; echo -ne .; done)
```

*If trasnfered data is appeared in ssh consoles in raw hex form you need to increase delay (receiving side isn't fast enoug).*

4. After sending is finished, press `Enter` and `Ctrl-D` in ssh console, then give following command to convert received file from hex to binary:

```
(while read -s l; do for c in $l; do printf "\x$c"; done; done) < temp.txt > file.bin
```

5. Check file length with the command: `(x=0; IFS=""; while read -d '' -s -r -n 1 c; do x=$(($x+1)); done; echo $x) < file.bin`.
6. And if the length matches (no data was lost during unreliable transmission) you can copy file to the desired location:

```
(IFS=""; while read -d '' -s -r -n 1 c; do printf "%c" "$c"; done) < file.bin > destination
```

Comment: Also if you have library copy at nonstandard location, you can still run dynamically linked application with the command: `/lib/ld-2.24.so --library-path /path-to-shared-lib /bin/cp ...`